# Jenkins Multijob filnaly result

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Multijob structure:

```
Master MultiJob Project (Job)
 |----- Phase 1
            |------> JOB A 
            |------> JOB D
 |----- Phase 2
            |------> JOB B
            |------> JOB D
 |----- Phase 2
            |------> JOB C
```

Job D is always failed, but it's Ok for this project. 
How I can exclude result job D from final results? (Because all other jobs is success, but final result is FAILED)

Comment: Can't you exclude or disable JOB D from the configuration as it is okay even if it fails?

Comment: It takes some additional info about project. No I cann't exclude or disable it from Multijob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to have the `Master MultiJob Project (Job)` successful irrespective of `JOB D`execution result. But, `JOB A`, `JOB B` and `JOB C` should be successful.

You can make the `Master Multijob Project (Job)` successful by using [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin).

Once you install this plugin in Jenkins, you will get `Groovy Postbuild` step in the `Post-build Actions` section. Choose `Groovy Postbuild` step and it will give an option to add Groovy scripts to manipulate your job behavior.

Add the following script there:

```
if( manager.build.@result == hudson.model.Result.FAILURE){
errpattern = ~/[FAILURE].*/;
manager.build.logFile.eachLine{ line ->
    errmatcher=errpattern.matcher(line)
    if (errmatcher.find()) {
        manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
    }
  }
}
```

What the above script will do is change the build status of your parent job to success if it fails. But, the issue here is it will change the build status to success for any child job failure in your phases.

You only want to ignore the FAILURE status of `JOB D` not the other jobs. So, what we can do is determine the execution results of `JOB A`, `JOB B` and `JOB C`. If any of them fails we can prevent the Groovy script from changing the build status of your parent job to SUCCESS.

Now, to determine the build result for `JOB A`,`JOB B` and `JOB C`

We can use the following:

```
JOBA_BUILD_STATUS=$(curl --silent "http://<jenkins_URL>/job/JOBA/$BUILD_ID/api/json" | jq -r '.result')

JOBB_BUILD_STATUS=$(curl --silent "http://<jenkins_URL>/job/JOBB/$BUILD_ID/api/json" | jq -r '.result')

JOBC_BUILD_STATUS=$(curl --silent "http://<jenkins_URL>/job/JOBC/$BUILD_ID/api/json" | jq -r '.result')
```

In the `Build` section of your multi-job configuration, after all the phases add `Execute shell` step and add the above scripts to it.

Now, let's tweak the groovy script to ignore `JOB D`'s build result and consider  the build result for `JOB A`,`JOB B` and `JOB C`.

```
if((manager.build.@result == hudson.model.Result.FAILURE) && ("SUCCESS".equals(manager.build.buildVariables.get("JOBA_BUILD_STATUS"))) && ("SUCCESS".equals(manager.build.buildVariables.get("JOBB_BUILD_STATUS"))) && ("SUCCESS".equals(manager.build.buildVariables.get("JOBC_BUILD_STATUS")))){
   errpattern = ~/[FAILURE].*/;
    manager.build.logFile.eachLine{ line ->
    errmatcher=errpattern.matcher(line)
    if (errmatcher.find()) {
        manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
    }
  }
}
```

Now, it will ignore the build result of `JOB D` and then check if the build results for `JOB A, B & C` are SUCCESS or not. If they are successful then it will change the build result of your Multijob to SUCCESS.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution to the problem, but unfortunately we can not install the plug-ins.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with groovy script. Add it as Post build action in your Multijob.

```
def subjobStatusMap = [:]

manager.build.getSubBuilds().each { subBuild->
      subJobName = subBuild.getJobName()
      subJobNumber = subBuild.getBuildNumber()
      job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(subBuild.getJobName())
      results = job.getLastCompletedBuild().getResult()

      subjobStatusMap.put((subJobName), results) 
}
manager.listener.logger.println(subjobStatusMap)

if(("SUCCESS".equals(subjobStatusMap.get("JOB_A").toString()))&& ("SUCCESS".equals(subjobStatusMap.get("JOB_B").toString())) && ("SUCCESS".equals(subjobStatusMap.get("JOB_C").toString()))) {
    manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- download Jenkins Plugin `Groovy Postbuild`
- add post-build step:Groovy Postbuild
- type code like this:

```java
import hudson.model.*

jobA = Hudson.instance.getJob("JobA")
jobB = Hudson.instance.getJob("JobB")
jobC = Hudson.instance.getJob("JobC")
jobD = Hudson.instance.getJob("JobD")

if("SUCCESS".equals(jobA.getLastBuild().getResult().toString())&&
"SUCCESS".equals(jobB.getLastBuild().getResult().toString())&&
"SUCCESS".equals(jobC.getLastBuild().getResult().toString())
){
        manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS

}
```

[See the script image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsipr.png)